# “My start day will be ..." or "My starting date will be ..."

Tags: grammar, modifiers, attributives

Which is correct:

> My start date will be

or

> My starting date will be

I mean to inform a company when I will be starting new job

Answer (score 2):

"Start date" is more common among American English speakers, while more BrE speakers use "starting date." "Starting date" is not wrong.

Here is a Google Ngram graph comparing the two phrases in English in genenral.

[image]

One well noted difference between American English and British English is that when forming compound nouns BrE speakers tend to favor the gerund, while AmE uses attributive nouns or bare infinitives extensively in compound nouns (which means AmE has more instances of the *noun + noun* or *verb + noun* patterns).

Most American English speakers thereby will find "start date" more natural and idiomatic, while a British English speaker will likely use both terms or lean toward "starting date."

Here is how the two terms compare on a BrE chart:

[image]

Below is how they fare in the body of American English works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say

- Start Date : correct
- Start Day : not used
- Starting Date : accurate enough but not used.

When starting a new job, the contract or verbal agreement often cite "start date", the date that you start the job.  Starting date makes sense but it sounds a bit wrong.